# Display Different DIVs For Mobile Devices

Tags: css, mobile

I have some `onMouseOver` functions that don't work particularly well on mobile devices. Would it be possible for me to have a different `DIV` displayed on mobile devices?

Here's a late response to your suggestions. Basically, I want a separate DIV (without the onMouseOver) if the display is mobile.

```
<!-- services -->
    <section class="services" id="services">
            <div class="container ptb">

                <div class="row">
                    <h2 class="centered mb"><b>SERVICES</b></h2>
                </div> <!-- Services Headline -->

<img src="assets/img/services-flip.png" height="50%" width="50%"
    onMouseOver="this.src='assets/img/services-list.png'"
    onMouseOut="this.src='assets/img/services-flip.png'" />

            </div> <!-- Content, Image -->
    </section>
<!-- end services -->
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get questions which give the audience the possibility to see what you have tried on your own?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I guess the answer is "yes, it is", but you're probably looking for particular techniques to do so :) which vary vastly (there are *a lot* of different ways to this and choosing a particular depends on the context). I suggest that you first google for available techniques and try if they work for you. If something doesn't work, you can post it as an answerable question like "I am using this technique: {technique description, code example} and this is the error I receive: {error description}". Check out this guide for writing questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here's a late response to your suggestions. Basically, I want a separate DIV (without the onMouseOver) if the display is mobile.

<!-- services -->
 <section class="services" id="services">
      <div class="container ptb">

       <div class="row">
        <h2 class="centered mb"><b>SERVICES</b></h2>
       </div> <!-- Services Headline -->

<img src="assets/img/services-flip.png" height="50%" width="50%"
 onMouseOver="this.src='assets/img/services-list.png'"
 onMouseOut="this.src='assets/img/services-flip.png'" />

      </div> <!-- Content, Image -->
 </section>
<!-- end services -->

Answer (score 0):

[Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) are your friend.

Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  div.mobile { display: block; }
  div.desktop { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys! I'm going to try learning media queries this weekend, and I'll get back to you all!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Media Queries, you can also use something like: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Essentially you can include a script like this, and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(jQuery.browser.mobile) {
      $('body').addClass('mobile');
    }
});
```

And based on the body class "mobile", hide / display the necessary divs. (this is the jQuery example, but you can do it using plain JS as well)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can .
Use  css's  CSS Media Queries 
Here is a great reference for  apple products screen sizes.
http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  left:0;
  left:0;
}

 #desktopView{
   background:rgb(50,50,80);
   display:block;
  }
  #mobileView{
    background:rgb(50,80,50);
    display:none;
  }
  #mobileLandscapeView{
    display:none;
    background:rgb(80,50,50);
  }


/* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */ 
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width : 667px){ 

  /* where you can hide unwanted DIV and show a special MOBILE DIV if desired */ 

  #desktopView{
    background:rgb(50,50,80);
    display:none;
  }
  #mobileView{
    background:rgb(50,80,50);
    display:block;  
  }
  #mobileLandscapeView{
    background:rgb(80,50,50);
    display:none;
  }

}

/* iPhone 6 in landscape */ 
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width : 667px) and (orientation : landscape) { 

   /* where you can hide unwanted DIV and show a special MOBILE DIV if desired */ 

  #desktopView{
    display:none;
  }
  #mobileView{
    display:none;  
  }
  #mobileLandscapeView{
    display:block;
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="desktopView">Should see in desktop mode</div>
<div id="mobileView">Should see in iPhone 6 vertical mode</div>
<div id="mobileLandscapeView">Should see in iPhone 6 landscape mode</div>
```